# Конфликт ip

Tags: arp

Нужно узнать, использует ли кто ip адрес linux-серверa в сети или нет.Нужно использовать только arp, т.е написать shell скрипт на подобии arpwatch.

Answer (score 2):

`ip a a <new_ip_address_server> dev <eth device>;ip a d <old_ip_server/mask> dev <eth device>;ping <old_ip_server>;ip n | grep <old_ip_server>`

Если вы понимаете о чем я?!

1. Ставим новый айпи на интерфейс
2. Старый удаляем
3. Пингуем старый
4. Смотрим в арп таблице какой мак соответствует старому айпи.

Answer (score 0):

Если сеть построена на вменяемых коммутаторах - выгреби с них arp таблицы, если это происходит нерегулярно -- заюзай snmptrap

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
arping -w2 -D -I eth0 10.0.0.1
```